# Compass not compiling Sass map

Tags: css, sass, compass-sass

I have a Sass map which Compass complains when compiling. I'm getting a syntax error. I have an [example of the code](http://sassmeister.com/gist/11463184) on Sassmeister and it compiles just fine.

Here is the Sass map and the Compass compile error:

```
$homepageShapes: (
    template1: (svg: "verticies.svg", top: 200px, left: 150px),
    template2: (svg: "full.svg", top: 300px, left: 30px),
    template3: (svg: "swipe_medium_right.svg", top: 300px, left: 30px),
    template4: (svg: "swipe_medium_left.svg", top: 300px, left: 30px),
    template5: (svg: "swipe_small_left.svg", top: 300px, left: 30px),
    template6: (svg: "swipe_small_right.svg", top: 300px, left: 30px),
    template7: (svg: "text_only.svg", top: 300px, left: 30px)
);
error workspace/submoduled-assets/styles/styleguide.scss (Line 2 of workspace/submoduled-assets/styles/modules/_node-homepage-rotator.scss: Invalid CSS after "    template1": expected ")", was ": (svg: "vertic...")
```

I have Sass v3.3.6 and Compass v0.12.6 installed.

Comment: might want to submit an issue on github...

Answer (score 0):

I went straight to the source. Chris Eppstein said that the pre-releases do support this feature. I would rather not use a pre-release, but I guess I will since sass maps is such an important feature.

Comment: I have done this as well (with `sass`), especially since I wanted to use some of the newest features. Haven't encountered any problems so far by doing this ;)